# Adding Header File Contents to Group Removes Content From Files

Tags: c++, doxygen

I defined the following group in Doxygen:

```
/**
 * @file CommandHandler.hpp
 */
#ifndef COMMAND_HANDLER_HPP
#define COMMAND_HANDLER_HPP

/** 
 * @defgroup CommandHandlers Command Handlers
 */

class CommandHandler
{
public:
    ...
```

Then I used the following to add the contents of a header file to the group:

```
/**
 * @file GetSystemStatistics.hpp
 */
#ifndef GET_SYSTEM_STATISTICS_HPP_
#define GET_SYSTEM_STATISTICS_HPP_

#include "CommandHandler.hpp"

/** @addtogroup CommandHandlers */
/*@{*/

class GetSystemStatistics : public CommandHandler
{
public:
    ...
/*@}*/
```

The documentation from the header file appears in the Modules -> Command Handlers section as I expected, but the documentation is now gone from the Files -> File List -> header.hpp section.

Is there a way I can configure Doxygen so that the documentation from the header file appears in both places (i.e. under Modules and Files)?  Is it a problem that I included a class definition in the header file that defines the group?  I placed the @defgroup in CommandHandler.hpp because it was a common header file for all derived classes that belong to the group.

Comment: I think you need to add more information for this issue . I tried it, but in my environment it works as expected. One thing you could try is to ensure that the `@file` tag is enclosed by the `@{` and the `@}` tags.

Comment: No problem, I added more of the source code and doxygen comments.  I also tried moving the location of the `@file` tag, but I did not see a difference.